# Generic lambda in custom binding adapter

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have a custom binding adapter with an attribute `onSelectItem` that expects a **generic** lambda expression:

```
<UsersSpinner
    <!-- more things -->

    app:onSelectItem="@{(item) -> usersViewModel.select(item)}"/>
```

This is the `UsersViewModel`'s `select` method's signature:

```
public void select(User user);
```

`UsersSpinner` extends from `MyCustomSpinner<T>`. This is the binding adapter:

```
  @BindingAdapter("onSelectItem")
    public static <T> void setOnSelectItem(MyCustomSpinner<T> view, final OnSelectItem<T> onSelectItem) {
        view.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                T item = (T) adapterView.getSelectedItem();
                onSelectItem.onSelectItem(item);
            }
        });
    }
```

Problem is that `UsersViewModel.select(User u)` expects an user, but here:

```
@{(item) -> viewModel.select(item)}
```

`item` is not a `User`, but a `Object`, because the generic parameter of `OnSelectItem<T>` is not being "applied". So, there is no method `UsersViewModel.select(Object o)` and I get a compilation error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, finally I have solved it by replacing this

```
app:onSelectItem="@{(item) -> usersViewModel.select(item)}"
```

with

```
app:onSelectItem="@{(item) -> usersViewModel.select((User)item)}"
```